# problems deploying openMRS.war to glassfish v.2

Tags: glassfish

I'm trying to deploy openMRS v.1.9.2 to a local VM running CentOS & Glassfish 2 for work. Unfortunately, I could not get it to work. Normally, I just download the standalone found at source forge. I just double-click the jar, and I'm good to go.

I normally just SSH into the the VM, so I first tried doing everything through a terminal. Here are the steps I took:

1. Using `wget`, retrieve the `.zip`
2. Create a `dir` (I just called it `/openmrs`), cd into the new directory, and then expand the `.zip`.
3. `cd` into the directory.
4. At this point, there are two options to start `openMRS`.

   - Run the `bash` script: `./run-on-linux.sh`
   - Run the `.JAR`: `java -jar [insert_jar_name].jar -commandline`

When I run the `.JAR`, I get a stack trace.

When I try to run the `bash` script, I get another error.

Anyways, I thought I found a potential solution in an `openMRS` `JIRA` ticket, [but it seems aimed at Glassfish 3, and not Glassfish 2 (which is what I need to use)](https://tickets.openmrs.org/browse/TRUNK-3410).

I then tried deploying the `.WAR` via the Glassfish admin UI. I thought it would work, but after going through the steps of selecting a language, whether or not to use demo data, etc. I received [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU9K8.png).

Does anyone have experience deploying openMRS to Glassfish 2.1.1? Unfortunately Glassfish 3 doesn't seem to be a realistic option. I would really appreciate any help here. Thanks.

Comment: Here's the stack trace (I can't post more than two links): http://pastebin.com/M0JYU6TV

Comment: The documentation here about troubleshooting MySQL doesn't seem to have anything applicable to my problem. There's no mention of the error message I'm getting: https://wiki.openmrs.org/display/docs/Troubleshooting+MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't solve my problem of not being able to successfully deploy openMRS to an instance of Glassfish v.2, I did manage to get myself further by just installing MySQL on the VM. Our work machines are all set up for postgres, so I think should have guessed earlier that not having a MySQL server installation was the problem.

[Here is a tutorial I used to install MySQL](http://wpguru.co.uk/2012/04/how-to-install-mysql-on-centos-2/)